# What type would be used for abstracting a JSX element's attributes into an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm still relatively green to typescript, and this has become more of a curiosity than needing to do it to make it functional.

If I abstract the attributes of the html input into it's own object, what would the type of **fileInputAttrs** be? I've looked into JSX.IntrinsicElements and the like but can't seem to find an interface for the native attributes of a `<input type='file'>`

```
render() {
    const fileInputAttrs: SomeType = {
        type: 'file',
        multiple: true,
        ref: (input: HTMLInputElement) => this.elFileInput = input,
        onChange: () => this.handleSelectedFile()
    };

    return (
        <div className={'blah'}>
            <input  {...fileInputAttrs} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the [React definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L3807). In this case it would be `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>` i.e. this:

```
const fileInputAttrs: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement> = {
    type: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    ref: (input: HTMLInputElement) => this.elFileInput = input,
    onChange: () => this.handleSelectedFile()
};
```